How to recess a subfloor for a curbless shower with TJI I-joists?
I'm building a curbless shower, and I need to recess my joists by about 2.75" to account for a 2" mud bed at its thinnest point. Upon removing my subfloor, I've seen that the joists are TJI I-joists. The shower area itself is 32" x 60", so I'll need to cut the top flange of two I joists:

My plan to reinforce the floor with a "telephone" looking piece like this:

I'd like to attach it with construction adhesive and screws, with the higher sides of the "telephone" (blue in the diagram) hitting the remaining flanges from each side (gold in the diagram), and the lower trough area of the "telephone" being recessed enough to accommodate the new OSB for recessed subfloor (transparent red in the diagram) and mud bed. I'd then like to add 2x4s in between the lower flange and the bottom of the telephone piece for extra support (pink in the diagram):

Prior to attaching the OSB, I would drill perpendicular supports (green in the diagram) (side view):
Top down view:

I would like to have a structural engineer review this in person, but any suggestions/recommendations prior to that would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

My advice is to not cut or modify the joist at all.  They are engineered to meet a specification and any modification will nullify that.  The consequences could be nothing or something very serious.  Either do not touch the joists and modify your shower plan, or get an engineering report on what exactly to do.

You really want a structural engineer for this.  Plain wood joists might  be able to be changed, but those I-joists are very picky about being cut.

You lower those joists 2.75 inches (the entire joist from end to end - easily done at the planning phase, not so easy now.) If you cut the flanges you're ignoring why I-joists work at all, and all the copious advice on how to install them the makers will happily supply (read your make and model off them and go look up the directions...)

Another approach is to ignore specifications for a second and just think about how an I-beam/I-joist handles load. You can visualise how a beam would bend as you press down on the middle of it; when the middle of the beam stays the same length, from the curve that the top flange must be compressed from end to end (as it gets shorter, relative to the middle) and the bottom flange must be tensioned from end to end (as it gets longer, relative to the middle). Wood is much stronger under compression than tension, so what your cut does is take out the part of the beam most capable of bearing load.

As others have stated, you definitely need a structural engineer for this.
We built a new house with a curbless shower and I-joist floor a few years ago, so I can tell you how the engineer approached it.
The joists are cut at both ends of the shower, and supported by two 4 by 8 beams that are supported by posts on two concrete pads.  There are two additional 4 by 8 beams sandwiched against these, but a couple inches lower.  These beams support the I joists under the shower at both ends.  There are 2 by 12s (or so) at both levels installed on edge like rim joists at the cut ends of the floor level joists and the shower level joists.
Here's a section in the plans that shows this detail:

This approach does not attempt to carry any floor load in the joists through the height change, instead completely separating the loads and carrying them vertically down to the ground.

Thanks a ton for sharing this... concrete is not going to be possible for me, but I'll share with the structural engineer and get his input. Maybe wood fittings will work.

I'm surprised the floor and shower floor don't share any support. Are they attached? Otherwise, how doesn't your caulk pop out? I'd expect differently sized support (house vs shower) to have substantially different displacement when loaded/unloaded.

@DaniëlvandenBerg - I have assumed that the sandwiched beams and "rim" joists at the ends are well nailed to each other.  (The builders added another "rim" joist at each end of the lowered shower joists that isn'r shown in this drawing.  I assume that also is well-nailed to the ones shown in the drawing.). No sign of any differential movement after 4 years.

Not saying these are good options, but they are possibilities.  You would need your local structural engineer or potential architect to check them out and confirm them.
A) Instead of sinking the sub floor to the desired height, raise the floor everwhere else so you wind up with a flush finish at the shower threshold.
B) Drop the joist to the required level.  This will mean lowering the support points, potentially redoing the ceiling below, and having to shim between the new joist and what the old joist supported outside the limits of the shower pan.
C)  Contact the joist manufacturer and tell them what you are planning to do and see if they have a solution that they will stand behind.  The manufacturer will most likely have a library or repair and strengthening options for joists that are damaged.  Side story:  Buddy was building a brand new home and had these same joist supporting his main floor.  Plumber came in to install the toilet and cored the drain and installed the goose neck in a way that took out the top flange and 3/4 of the web.  The joist suppliers came up with a way to fix the situation and kept the warranty intact.
D) Install new shorter joists at a tighter spacing.  New support points will be needed at the ends, and shimming to make up the difference between new and old joist height would be required.  Ceiling line of the floor below can be maintained.
E) Turn the joist into a solid wood beam.  Adding width increases strength, but not as efficient as increasing depth.  The engineer/architect will tell you the minimum width required based on the the depth in the shower pan area that can be accommodated.
F) Similar to answer given by Mark, you can basically turn the shower pain opening into a hole in the floor.  You will need to cut the joists at the pan and add transverse framing to support the cut joist.  The transverse framing will then need to be supported on reinforced joists on either side of the shower pan.  Rebuild the flooring support as required under the shower pan and between the transverse pieces .
